# Throwing "Unable to find a renderer for /view_object/sample.mustache"

Tags: dropwizard

Hi i need to use mustache with dropwizard, but unable to setup properly.
please have a look...

service.java

```
public class Service extends  Application<ServiceConfiguration>{



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Service().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<ServiceConfiguration> bootstrap) {
         bootstrap.addBundle(new ConfiguredAssetsBundle("/assets/", "/","index.html"));
         bootstrap.addBundle(new ViewBundle<ServiceConfiguration>());
        }

    @Override
    public void run(ServiceConfiguration config, Environment environment)throws Exception {

        environment.jersey().register(new ViewResource());


    }

}
```

ViewResource.java

```
package resource;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import view_object.UserSample;
import view_object.UsersView;

@Path("/views")
@Produces("text/html;charset=UTF-8")
public class ViewResource {

    public ViewResource() {
        super();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/usersample")
    public UsersView fetch(){
        List<UserSample> users = new LinkedList<UserSample>();
        users.add(
            new UserSample("user1","user1","Admin", "prit")

        );
        users.add(
                 new UserSample("user2","user2","DBA", "deepika")
        );

        return new UsersView(users);
    }
}
```

UserView.java

```
package view_object;

import java.util.List;

import io.dropwizard.views.View;

public class UsersView extends View {
    private final List<UserSample> users;

    public UsersView(List<UserSample> users) {
        super("sample.mustache");
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<UserSample> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

UserSample.java

```
package view_object;


public class UserSample {


    private String username;


    private String password;


    private String displayName;


    private String displayRole;

    public UserSample() {

    }


    public UserSample(String username, String password, String displayName,
            String displayRole) {

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.displayRole = displayRole;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }


    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }


    public String getDisplayRole() {
        return displayRole;
    }


    public void setDisplayRole(String displayRole) {
        this.displayRole = displayRole;
    }


}
```

sample.mustache (Path is "assets/partial/sample.mustache")

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Users</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {{#users}}
        <div>
            <p>Username: {{username}}</p>
            <p>Displayname: {{displayName}}</p>
        </div>
        {{/users}}
    </body>
</html>
```

in yaml i have specified

```
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /
  adminContextPath: /admin
  rootPath: '/api/*'
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 9000
  requestLog:
    timeZone: UTC
    appenders:
      - type: console
        threshold: ALL
        timeZone: UTC
        target: stdout
      - type: file
        currentLogFilename: ./log/requests.log
        threshold: ALL
        archive: true
        archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./log/requests-%d.log.gz
        archivedFileCount: 15
        timeZone: UTC


assets:
  overrides:
   /: src/main/resource/assets/
```

and also configured ServiceConfiguration.

now my problem is when i hit "http://localhost:9000/api/views/usersample"

it throws "Unable to find a renderer for /view_object/sample.mustache"

please help me out what wrong i am doing here..
I am using dropwizard 0.8.1 and also i have added related dependencies in maven

Comment: Did you add mustache to your dependencies ?
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
 <artifactId>dropwizard-views-mustache</artifactId>
 <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>